# Java Static final alternatives for use with Spring DI

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a class that I wanted to have `static final` variables.

```
public static final Map<String, Long> ID_MAP;
```

I wanted to be able to inject the map via Spring. This can't be done b/c it is a `static final`. My alternative was to declare it as `static` and use Spring with a setter. Something like

```
public void setIDMapSpring (long iDMapSpring){
   ID_MAP = iDMapSpring;
```

This, however, means that another class can come change the value. Are there any alternatives that I can try. I was thinking of having a Singleton with the Map as a `final` field but I've still to figure out how to pass the Map, and possibly other variables I want marked `final`, to the `getInstance` method. Also, I struggle to find the simplest and least complex solution.

Comment: Simplest and least complex solution would be to make the map non-final. In a sense, it really isn't final anyway since it's being changed at run-time.

Answer (score 3):

Make the map a field and inject a singleton.

Comment: Would the class be the singleton or the map? `public class SingletonID { Map<String,Long> map; private static getInstance(Map<String,Long> aMap){ if(theInstance == null) etc..`

Comment: The map would be the singleton. This is what making it a static field really means: "There is just one such Map"

Comment: Would this involve using `getBean("mapSingleton")` or something like that in my class? The reason I ask is b/c I am using GWT and this will be a shared class, which means that external jars can't be used since it all gets converted to javaScript by GWT. I know that spring beans are singletons by default and I don't see how else to make the map a singleton without using external libraries inside the class.

Comment: Its really up to you how you do your injection. You could just pass it in the constructor, you could configure Spring to do it. What ever fits the rest of your app best. I can't advice on GWT though

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about an outside class changing the value after Spring sets it, you could integrate a flag into your class that only lets the field be set once. Say you initialize a static `AtomicBoolean` called "CAN_SET_ID_MAP" to true. Then, in the map's setter:

```
if (CAN_SET_ID_MAP.compareAndSet (true, false)) {
  ID_MAP = iDMapSpring;
} else {
  throw new IllegalStateException ("ID_MAP already set");
}
```

There are other ways to do it. You probably want to use a thread-safe form of protection regardless.